# On an MVC Site can you prioritise Url Rewrite module in IIS to overide MVC routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, url-rewriting

I have an MVC site which has routes which I need to redirect with the IIS Url ReWrite module as I cannot rebuild the site (don't ask). So I thought I could use the IIS Url ReWriter and enter some web.config values to perform the redirect. Problem is the MVC route is getting handled first and so the url rewriter module is never hit.

is there a way to make the Url ReWriter the first handler then fall back to the MVC routing?

My environment is MVC2 c# Asp.NET 3.5 on IIS 7.5 Win Server 2008 R2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ASP.NET 2.0, 4.0? What MVC version? Is the site running in Classic or Integrated more? You should provide this information in the question as it's quite important to know your environment to be able to repro quickly.

Comment: is the pool running in classic or integrated pipeline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i have found that I cannot do this without creating an HttpModule. A simple thing to do really, create the code for the module by using IHttpModule then register it in the web config as so:

```
public class HttpRedirectModule: IHttpModule
    {

        public HttpRedirectModule()
        {

        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(ContextBeginRequest);

        }

        void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
            if (application.Application["Redirects"] == null)
            {
                var repository = Factory.GetInstance<IRepository>();
                application.Application["Redirects"] = repository.GetAll<Redirect>();
            }

            var redirects = (IList<Redirect>) application.Application["Redirects"];
            if (application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "/default.aspx")
            {
                foreach (var redirect in redirects)
                {
                    var regex = new Regex(redirect.FromPath);
                    Match match = regex.Match(application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {

                        application.Response.Clear();
                        if (redirect.StatusCode == 301)
                        {
                            application.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            application.Response.StatusCode = 301;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            application.Response.Status = "302 Moved temporarily";
                            application.Response.StatusCode = 302;
                        }
                        application.Response.AddHeader("Location", redirect.ToPath);
                        application.Response.End();

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }


<system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="RedirectsModule" />
      <add name="RedirectsModule" type="MyCode.HttpModules.HttpRedirectModule, MyCode" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any code into your global.asax before the URL routing is added.